# What does "qué lo que" mean?

Tags: coloquialismos

I recently asked a spanish speaking person from Columbia what  `'qué lo que'`  means.

They gave me a puzzled look. I was always under the impression it means 'what's up.'

I found it odd that she didn't understand it, nor she seem to recognize "que" as a word

either. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please tell us where you heard that this means "What's up?" ? Thanks. Moderators: Please do not delete. Thanks.

Comment: If you heard this from someone in the Caribbean region, they may have actually said "¿Qué es lo que es?", but with the omission of final S in the Caribbean accent.

Comment: Ok, so you posted that you heard it in Mexico and a mod deleted it. Can you please confirm it was Mexico and can you provide a link with an example? que lo que as such is meaningless in Spanish.

Comment: He probably gave you a look because it's an expression which isnt used in all spanish speaking countries

Comment: Para los que vayan a añadir más respuestas, por favor **escriban la tilde en el primer *qué*** ¿o ya se olvidaron las reglas de acentuación?

Answer (score 4):

It's documented to be a Dominican expression.

[Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=que%20lo%20que):

> **qué lo que**
> **Dominican greeting.**
>
> 1. What's up
>    Guy 1: Qué lo que loco.
>    Guy 2: Nah, aqui chillin, tu sabe como es.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/que_lo_que):

> **Interjection**/**phrase**
> **qué lo que**
>
> (idiomatic, slang) what's up, wassup, what is it, what it is, what is what it is, what is what, what are you doing, what's happening, what's going on

According to this [Dominican dictionary](https://www.colonialtours.com/diccionario.htm), ***Qué lo que*** is a shortened form of the expression ***Qué es lo que hay*** (literally "What is what there is")

This [site](https://www.wyzant.com/resources/answers/694046/what-does-que-lo-que-klk-in-chat-mean) tells that *klk* used in chat means ***¿qué es lo que es?*** (literally "What is what it is?").

The fact it seems very localized likely explains why your Columbian friend didn't know it. She might be familiar with this similar expression: *[quiubo/quihubo](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewWrongentry.php?idForum=23&idThread=1439864&lp=esde&lang=es)* from ***¿Qué hubo?*** (literally "what happened?").

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that the demonym for a native of Colombia does not have the letter U anywhere. Just like the name of the country itself, it's spelled with two Os: "C-O-L-O-M-B-I-A-N."

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Qué lo que?

would be taken too as:

> "what's up?"   "what about you?"

Comment: In what country?

Comment: esto en México amigo.

Comment: Please show us a link with that usage.

Answer (score 2):

The expression "qué lo que", is Hispanic street slang used mainly by young generations. It could be interpreted as:

- What's going on?
- What's up?
- What's happening?

It's a very informal way to greet someone, you use it with friends but not with family.

I have seen it used the most in Central America, Mexico and the Caribbean; not so much in South America.

Comment: Please provide proof., Thanx.

Comment: Proof of what ? once again. This is a very street slang language use by young generation. What more proof than been hispanic and have exposure to it all my life

Answer (score 1):

That means that, that what, that whatever, what, to what, than, as it does in, the thing is that, etc, it depends on the context. "Lo que" can be translated as "that" or "what". They function as relative pronouns that can introduce a clause that provides more information about what lo que or lo cual refer to.

https://www.rae.es/dpd/que

> 2.2. Introduce el segundo término de una comparación propia, es decir, aquella en la que se comparan dos entidades diferentes en relación con una determinada noción o magnitud. La **conjunción** que va siempre precedida, inmediatamente o no, de un adjetivo o adverbio de sentido comparativo (mejor, peor, mayor, menor, igual, más, menos, antes, después, etc.) o de un sustantivo multiplicativo o fraccionario (doble, triple, mitad, etc.): Tu automóvil es mejor que el mío; Su hermano pequeño es más alto que él; Mi maleta llegó después que yo; Ahora gano el doble que hace un año. En cambio, se emplea la preposición de, y **no la conjunción** que, para introducir oraciones de relativo sin antecedente expreso que denotan, no una entidad distinta, sino grado o cantidad en relación con la magnitud que se compara: «Le pagaré el doble **de lo que** marque el taxímetro» (Ribera Sangre [Esp. 1988]); «El Viejo sabe del testigo más **de lo que** aparenta» (Pozo Noche [Esp. 1995]); «Me despierto varias horas antes **de lo que** solía» (Téllez Trastornos [Méx. 1995]). Obsérvese, a este respecto, la diferencia entre estos dos enunciados: Eso importa más **que lo que** tú dices [=A importa más que B], frente a Eso importa más **de lo que** tú dices [=A importa más **de lo que** tú dices que importa].

> 2.2.5. También se usa la **conjunción** que en estructuras contrastivas del tipo yo que tú...; tú, al contrario que él...; o él, al revés que su hija...: «Yo que usted lo pensaría» (Lynch Dedos [Arg. 1977]); «Yo pienso, al contrario que mi admirado Manuel Hidalgo, que las guerras son muy peligrosas» (Mundo [Esp.] 12.5.99). No debe usarse en su lugar la preposición de, uso achacable en muchos casos al influjo de otras lenguas, como el catalán, donde se emplea en estas construcciones la preposición: «Yo de Leguina no dimitiría» (País [Esp.] 1.4.85); «Porque Yeltsin, al contrario de Gorbachov, reniega del marxismo-leninismo» (Universal [Ven.] 21.4.93); debió decirse Yo que Leguina y Yeltsin, al contrario que Gorbachov. Pero si con al contrario y al revés el segundo término es un **grupo nominal** que encierra una oración de **relativo**, debe usarse de y no que: Yo, al contrario **de lo que** tú piensas, creo que es mejor así (y no Yo, al contrario que lo que tú piensas...); Eso se hará al revés de como se dijo en un principio (y no Eso se hará al revés que como se dijo...). Pero si con al contrario y al revés el segundo término es un grupo nominal que encierra una **oración de relativo**, debe usarse de y no que: Yo, al contrario **de lo que** tú piensas, creo que es mejor así (y no Yo, al contrario **que lo que** tú piensas...); Eso se hará al revés de como se dijo en un principio (y no Eso se hará al revés que como se dijo...).

- "..**es que lo que** pasa.." (=the thing is that sometimes...)
- "Así **que lo que** insinúas me parece bien" (=so what)
- "Debemos asegurarnos **de que lo que** hacemos tenga un sentido"(=that what we do)
- Él trabaja harto para estar seguro **de que lo que** entra y sale(=what or that)
- Más puro **que lo que** encontramos en allá (than)
- Así que espero **que lo que** toquemos sea de ese estilo (=that or what)
- Hay una cosa que quiero decir primero que todo, **que lo que** es válido para nosotros debería serlo para ustedes (=that what)
- Una ruta que difiere **de lo que** cabría esperar (=to what)

Comment: Está mal. Es *qué lo que*, el primer *qué* es interrogativo y no un relativo

Answer (score 1):

“Qué lo que” or “KLK” when texting is a Dominican slang for saying what’s up.

Source: trust the dominican bruh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

"Qué lo que" used as "What's going on?" comes from "Qué es lo que (pasa)" or "Qué es lo que (es)". In some spanish accents people pronounce it without the "s" in "es".

Answer (score 0):

Some examples may help, imagine these conversations:

In Spanish, you could say:

 - ¿Qué piensas?

 - Yo pienso que lo que tú dijiste es cierto

In English, it would mean:

 - What do you think?

 - I think that what you said is true.

Another example,

In Spanish:

 - Dile que lo que vio es real

In English:

 - Tell him that what he saw is real

The first "que" is "that", and "lo que" is "what".
You could imagine "Lo que" as kind of "the thing which".

If you think of "que lo que" as two parts, "que" + "lo que",

In Spanish:

 - Lo que tú viste es real.

 - ¿Qué dijiste?

 - Yo dije que lo que tú viste es real.

In English:

 - What you saw is real.

 - What did you say?

 - I said that what you saw is real.

Comment: Está mal. Es *qué lo que*, el primer qué es interrogativo y no un relativo

Answer (score 0):

"Qué lo que" is dominican slang for "Whats up". It probably doesn't mean anything, anywhere else

Comment: This does not seem to add much to the existing answers. Can you edit to expand on how it differs from them?

Answer (score 0):

Significa: "¿Qué (es) lo que (pasa)?"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25638)